# iOS Memory - VM: CG Image and IO Surface

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I'm trying to find out if my app is managing memory correctly, and I see 2 things in `profiler`, that I'm wondering about. I use a lot of images loaded from `PHAsset's`. When I minimize the app all these images are deinitialized. But I still see a lot of memory taken by: `VM: CG Image` and `VM: IO Surface` - few hundreds MB. I don't know what these are, and if they should be removed from the memory. Is this some kind of caching maybe? Should I be worried, that they stay in memory, or is this ok? Can I somehow force clearing these to test?

Comment: did you get any solution for VM: IOS Surface

Comment: anyone got solution for this?